# How can i change the database schema depending on the message value in Kafka Connect?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I want to change schema on insert in PostgreSql depends on value message when i producer message to kafka connect?
How can i do that?

I tried using each topic for a different schema type, but this is not what i want.
eg: Topic name: country_city
`{ cityId: 1 }`
will insert into schema: country_1
`{ cityId: 2 }`
will insert into schema: country_2

Answer (score 0):

The schema/table that is used depends exclusively on the topic name, not values within each record.

You will need to use Kafka Connect Transforms to override the "outgoing topic name" to control where data is written in a database.

However, if you have numbered tables in your database, that is likely an anti-pattern and you should be using relations instead.

Comment: I research about STM but couldn't find a way to change the topic name based on the value of the message

Comment: You'll need to find or write your own transform. There isn't such one builtin.